Ligatures not displaying on website but fine on Google Fonts
My website is trying to display the letters "ل" and "ا", together they typically become "لا"
However, my website (hugo static site) is not rendering the ligature as I would expect,

or as I myself would see from Google Fonts

The code for my website's CSS is here: https://github.com/adehad/dhikr-hub/blob/d58c4e38299983676217e382774cae137d4a980e/site/assets/_custom.scss#L21
The website URL with an example is here: https://adehad.github.io/dhikr-hub/qasidas/al-mashrab_al-ahna/#30
I obtained the woff files using https://gwfh.mranftl.com/fonts/scheherazade-new?subsets=arabic,latin
But I had the same results when using the ones provided by the font creator (from the About page on the Google fonts link).
I have tried forcing ligatures to be enabled, but still have the same results
font-feature-settings: "liga" 1;
font-variant-ligatures: normal;

I have tried Firefox and Chromium based browsers, both seeing the same result. Which aligns with a configuration issue with my side, especially as the font also works with the Google Font preview.
Is there a possibility that some build step in the hugo process is affecting the fonts? They are using Dart SASS, but I am not fully aware if that is significant.
Any further advice on why this ligature is not being applied, and what further options I might have?

I am struggling to producing reproducible example.
My attempt below made by copying the HTML generated by hugo, then recreating the relevant CSS as either inline styles or inline CSS in a single HTML displays correctly on my end.
Example below now reproduces
<html lang="en-us" dir="ltr"
    style="--arabic-font-perc: 253%; --transliteration-font-perc: 80%; --translation-font-perc: 85%;">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <meta property="og:locale" content="en_us">
    <meta property="og:type" content="article">

    <!-- Google Fonts Direct Import -->
    <!--
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Scheherazade+New:wght@400;500;600;700&display=swap"
        rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- Equivalent to Wesbite -->
    <style>
        :root {
            --arabic-font-family: 'Scheherazade New';
            --arabic-font-perc: 200%;
        }

        @font-face {
            font-family: 'Scheherazade New';
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: 400;
            font-display: swap;
            src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/scheherazadenew/v15/4UaZrFhTvxVnHDvUkUiHg8jprP4DOwFmO24p.woff2)format("woff2");
        }

        .arabic {
            font-family: var(--arabic-font-family), sans-serif;
            font-size: var(--arabic-font-perc);
            letter-spacing:.33px;
        }
    </style>

</head>


<body dir="ltr">
    <main class="container flex">
        <div style="min-width:20rem; flex-grow:1; padding:1rem">
            <article
                style="transition:.2s ease-in-out; transition-property:transform,margin,opacity,visibility; will-change:transform,margin,opacity">
                <table style="text-align:center">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr class="arabic">
                            <td>بِالْأَثَرِ</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </article>
        </div>
    </main>
</body>

</html>




Could you extract just enough code to show the problem and put it into your question. The problem with external sites is they may disappear in future, or get mended, so rendering your question useless for future readers. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

I've made an example to the best of my ability, but it fails to capture the incorrect behaviour I am seeing (ie my example renders as I would expect), which is not ideal. I'm happy to give more attempts if any further pointers could be given

I can't see that we can help without seeing code that produces the problem. I've run your code as given and as you say, it works OK. You need to have a very thorough search in your browser devtools inspect facility to see exactly (and I mean exactly!) what CSS is being applied and also exactly what fonts have been loaded.

Indeed I appreciate the comments. I was looking for css properties with 'font' in the name, but turns out it was one related to 'letter'. Got there in the end!

After further digging it was found that the Hugo theme being used modified the letter-spacing, specifically it was set as: letter-spacing:.33px;.
Specifically at the body level. As expected this cascaded and affected the Arabic ligatures in the nested elements.
The solution was therefore to modify the CSS as following:
.arabic {
    font-family: var(--arabic-font-family), sans-serif;
    font-size: var(--arabic-font-perc);
    letter-spacing: normal; // This is the solution !
}



